# How to invoke JavaScript when dragging starts?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i am working on drag and drop tables like in this example:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dndTable.jsf

and i was wondering if it's possible to invoke JS code to hide/show components when start dragging an item.

please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimeFaces using jQuery draggable interaction you need to check [this](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events) out. Kickoff example:

```
$(function() {
  $( ".ui-dt-c" ).draggable({
      start: function() {
          alert(1);
      },
      drag: function() {
          alert(2);
      },
      stop: function() {
          alert(3);
      }
  });
});
```

As you can see this is firing recurring alert events because of the `drag` func. you can change it as you wish. Also you can try to change class to `.ui-dt-c ui-draggable`. Like in the jQuery example, you can to select the element by it's ID and override the function however, `p:dataTable` id's are messed up so selecting element by it's `class` makes more sense to me.