# Invoke JavaScript when specific tab is clicked

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i am exploring  the tab components in primefaces
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabviewChangeListener.jsf
, and i was wondering if it's possible to invoke a JavaScript when a specific tab is being clicked.

please advise, thanks.

Comment: From [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16262698/1065197), please first **try something** and then come here with the question.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, sometimes i have ideas to try and sometimes i don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to hook up on tab change events:

1. Use `onTabChange` attribute of `<p:tabView>` tag to execute a callback function on the appropriate event:

   ```
   <p:tabView onTabChange="handleTabChange(index)">
   //tabs
   </p:tabView>
   ```
2. Use `oncomplete` attribute of `<p:ajax>` tag to execute a JS function when AJAX call completes successfully:

   ```
           <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{tabBean.onTabChange}" oncomplete="handleOncomplete(xhr, status, args)"/>
   ```

Comment: when i use the method onTabChange="handleTabChange(event, index)" and make a JS function, i get the error that index is not defined

Comment: i am applying above onTabChange method on p:accordionPanel and i am not using any p:ajax events on the component.

Comment: There was a bug in PrimeFaces documentation. Now it's tested and working. `<p:accordionPanel>` has such attribute as well.